# Error creating a global CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift

**Apple Docs** suggest not to store your `CLLocationManager` in a local variable. So I created a global constant outside the scope of my `ViewController` class just after the `import` statements. Trying to access the constant inside the class, however, throws compiler errors:

[image: Xcode example screenshot]

A similarly declared `globalDictionary`constant of type `NSMutableDictionary` seems to be accessible inside the class.

What is it that I am doing wrong here? **Why does the above not work?**

---

**Code**:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CoreLocationExample
//
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Foundation

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let globalDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

//    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        let dict = [
            "name":"John"
        ]
        globalDictionary.addEntries(from: dict)
        print(globalDictionary)
    }
}
```

---

*Using Swift 3 on Xcode Version 8.3.1*

Comment: add your code..

Comment: 2017 and someone still uses global variables... Create some class, i.e. `MyLocationManager` which will hold `CLLocationManager`. Access `MyLocationManager` via singleton instance

Comment: why you are using "let" with a variable ???

Comment: @mag_zbc 2017 and someone (many people actually) are learning how to code...Thanks for the tip. I assume that is the standard way of creating a `CLLocationManager`. Why does the above not work though?

Comment: @matloobHasnain Because `CLLocationManager` is a class( i.e.reference type). So even if the instance `locationManager` points to has its properties changed, the reference is still to that same instance. Had it been a value type (like a struct), it would have been a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Docs suggest not to store your CLLocationManager in a local variable.
It means do not create local instance inside a method / function.

please declare like this.

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
//CLLocation Manager
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var locValue = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
```

}

CLLocation Manager or globalDictionary Inside the class.

Comment: "Apple Docs suggest not to store your CLLocationManager in a local variable. It means do not create local instance inside a method / function." - Interesting perspective. Not totally convinced though. **Isn't a class variable still 'local' since it is scoped and limited to use inside that class?** In your answer, I wouldn't be able to access the `locationManager` outside of the `AppDelegate` (e.g. inside a `UIViewController` subclass).

Comment: yes it will, let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
  appDelegate.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. Hadn't thought of that! I gather that using a singleton instance is a common solution for creating a global `CLLocationManager`. Any reason why the error for `locationManager` and none for `globalDictionary` as in the screenshot above?

Answer (score 0):

use singleton class for this

import UIKit
import CoreLocation

public class LocationManager: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
public static let sharedInstance = LocationManager()
public lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
var globalDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

public override init() {
    super.init()
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    let dict = [
        "name":"John"
    ]
    self.globalDictionary.addEntries(from: dict)
    print(self.globalDictionary)
}

// MARK: - Location Manager Delegate
public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    print(error)
}

public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
    let newLocation: CLLocation? = locations.last
    let locationAge: TimeInterval? = -(newLocation?.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow)!
    if Double(locationAge!) > 5.0 {
        return
    }
    if Double((newLocation?.horizontalAccuracy)!) < 0 {
        return
    }
}

public  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

}
```

}

Comment: Creating a singleton class sounds like a good solution for avoiding a local variable. This was also suggested by @mag_zbc before. Why subclass `NSObject` though? In any case, your answer does not address the question of why the error is being generated which is what I was primarily looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in the following way -

```
class LocationTracker {
static var locationManager: CLLocationManager? = LocationTracker.sharedLocationManager()

class func sharedLocationManager() -> CLLocationManager {

    let lockQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "self")
    lockQueue.sync {
        if _locationManager == nil {
            _locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            _locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            _locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            _locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        }
    }
    return _locationManager!
}
```

}

And when you need to call it in your code, you can do the below -

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager? = LocationTracker.sharedLocationManager()
```

you can then add other Location related methods in this class as well like for startt tracking, update location, stoptracking etc.

Comment: That code just looks weird. Why the class func is named `sharedLocationManager` if it just returns new instance?

Comment: Sorry didn't get that. It return new instance if there is not an existing instance for it otherwise it returns the existing instance. Also the new instance is created in a synchronised block.Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: "It return new instance if there is not an existing instance for it otherwise it returns the existing instance." - no, it doesn't return existing instance, it would if `_locationManager` was static. Also, what's the reason for synchronized block if it's only invoked during `LocationTracker` instantiation?

Comment: It looks like you tried to make an Objective-C singleton, only using Swift

Comment: Yeah I tried doing ObjC to Swift and missed the static keyword there. My bad.

Comment: If you access this shared instance outside by calling `LocationTracker.sharedLocationManager()`, then what is the purpose of `locationManager` local variable in `LocationTracker`?

Comment: Yup, the intention was to have it outside so that all the other methods in this class that the person makes in the future related to location tracking can access this variable. There was no need to have a local variable inside the method.